# Win8.1 - Is there a way to change AppLocale for one user?

Tags: windows-8.1

I've been wondering if there is a way in Win8.1 to change AppLocale (Control Panel->Region->Administrative->Change System Locale) for just one user. When I changed it, it changed locale for all users, which is not what I want.

Any tips?

Comment: I want to play Japaneese Visual Novel, and need to change to applocale to this language. Changing it however, messes up both Steam and f.lux...

Comment: I realized my comment talked about a folder, its not a folder, apparently its a tool which isn't supported on anything after Windows XP apparently.  Update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13209 Its a stand-alone AppLocale changer. So it will work for individual apps rather than the whole user profile (or system profile)